# How can I know what the boundary of $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}((r_n-4^{-n},r_n+4^{-n}) \cap ]0,1[)$ is?

Tags: measure-theory

How can I know what the boundary of $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}((r_n-4^{-n},r_n+4^{-n}) \cap ]0,1[)$ is? Where $r_n$ are rational numbers.

Problem, the intervals are "spread" and I don't even know if they're disjoint.

Comment: Please check if the $r^{-n}$ is correct. Also, what are the $r_n$?

Comment: The actual set will depend on the choice of ordering for the rational numbers. However, some things can be said. First of all, since every rational is an interior point of your set, then the complementary set is a subset of $(0, 1) \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Second, and this should be more or less where the question is leading you to, notice that the measure of the set given has an upper bound of $\sum_{n \geq 1} 2 \cdot 4^{-n} = \tfrac23$. Thus, the complementary set has measure at least $1/3$. In particular, it is not empty.

Comment: If the $r_n$-s are just rational numbers, then it depends on which ones they are the order in which they are chosen. If the $r_n$-s are *the* rational numbers of $(0,1)$, then the boundary in $(0,1)$ of your set $A$ is simply $(0,1)\setminus A$ (and its boundary in $\Bbb R$ is $[0,1]\setminus A$).

Comment: @Gae.S. Why do we say that the boundary is all those other points? Rather than only those "surrounding" intervals of $A$? Isn't your def. for "exterior"? I'd imagine that the boundary of my intervals should be "the union of the end points"?

Comment: In my book, the exterior of a set is the interior of its complement, and the boundary is the set of all points which are neither in the interior nor in the exterior. What I said was that (theorem:) in the circumstance I was describing the boundary is the thing I said.

Comment: @Gae.S. Yeah so my case is not "rational number", but "an union of intervals surrounding rationals".